# junit report visualization tools

Tags: testing, junit, report, xunit

I'm looking for an junit report visualization tool. I have a set of xml reports generated by a custom test-suite tool and I want to be able to visualize their history. A plugin for jenkins would be ideal, but a standalone application is also ok.

The one thing I have found so far that seems to fit the spec:

http://junitth.sourceforge.net/

Though I am a bit wary of using this as development seems to have stopped a year or two ago.

Any suggestions welcome.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a new tool called **[Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/)**. This is not exactly what you described because it uses its own XML files which can be automatically generated during test run via **[provided](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/tree/master/allure-junit-adaptor)** JUnit RunListener. However it supports a lot of test-related features like custom test description, grouping by features and stories, adding attachments, etc. You could try to adapt your custom XML to their **[schema](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-model/src/main/resources/allure.xsd)** and then generate the visualization with **[standalone tool or plugin](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki#generating-report)**.